# Undefinied Index for an index that exists

Tags: php, laravel

I think its just been a long day. Please help me understand why this is saying its an unknown index. The parent [0] could be anything because its essentially a random number, so I am using foreach to loop through each such array group:

```
    if (isset($request->new_grades) && count($request->new_grades)>0) {
        Log::debug('main array:');
        Log::debug(print_r($request->new_grades, true));
        $new_count_confirm = 0;
        foreach ($request->new_grades as $new_grade) {
            Log::debug('This is the $new_grade:');
            Log::debug(print_r($new_grade, true));
            Log::debug('This is the course: '. $new_grade['course']);
    }
}
```

Log output:

```
[2021-01-14 11:37:24] local.DEBUG: main array:  
[2021-01-14 11:37:24] local.DEBUG: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ["course"] => Test Course
            ["module"] => Test Module
            ["year"] => 2020
            ["grade"] => 20
        )

)  
[2021-01-14 11:37:24] local.DEBUG: This is the $new_grade:  
[2021-01-14 11:37:24] local.DEBUG: Array
(
    ["course"] => Test Course
    ["module"] => Test Module
    ["year"] => 2020
    ["grade"] => 20
)    

[2021-01-14 11:37:24] local.ERROR: Undefined index: course
```

I hope this

Comment: ?Invisible character somewhere

Comment: Try [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of print_r

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Definitely not Rafal for the var_export suggestion which made me see the error of my ways. print_r wasnt showing the output of the quotation mark as per OP but this showed it:

```
array (
  '"course"' => 'Test Course',
  '"module"' => 'Test Module',
  '"year"' => '2020',
  '"grade"' => '20',
)
```

The name of the html input was getting assigned the quotes:

```
$('<input />', { class: 'form-control', id:'new_grades['+ new_course_counter +'][course]', name:'new_grades['+ new_course_counter +']["course"]', placeholder:'Course'})
```

Change the above to exclude the quotes and its working now:

```
$('<input />', { class: 'form-control', id:'new_grades['+ new_course_counter +'][course]', name:'new_grades['+ new_course_counter +'][course]', placeholder:'Course'})
```